# react button conditional rendering not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

working on a cart app in a udemy course  - the problem is when the quantity gets bought it supposed to make the button disabled but its not working, only showing the add to cart button without disabling it when quantity are zero
data.countInStock seems not to be updating

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import Rating from './Rating';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Store } from '../Store';

function Product(props){
 const {product} = props;

const {state , dispatch:ctxDispatch} = useContext(Store);
const {cart: {cartItems}} = state

const addToCartHandler = async (item )=>{
  const existItem = cartItems.find((x)=> x._id === product._id);
   const quantity = existItem ? existItem.quantity+1:1 ; 

  const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/products/${item._id}`);
  if(data.countInStock < quantity){
      window.alert('sorry product is out of stock')
      return;
  }
   ctxDispatch({
       type:'CART_ADD_ITEM' 
       , payload:{...item , quantity},
   });
  };
  

return(

    <Card>


    <Link to={`/product/${product.slug}`}> 
      <img src={product.image} className="card-img-top" alt={product.name} />
    </Link>
    <Card.Body>
    <Link to={`/product/${product.slug}`}>
        <Card.Title>{product.name}</Card.Title>
    </Link>
    <Rating rating={product.rating} numReviews={product.numReviews} />
    <Card.Text>${product.price}</Card.Text>

    {  product.countInStock === 0 ? (

      
      <Button  color="light" disabled={true} >  Out of stock</Button>
      
    ):(
      
      <Button onClick={() => addToCartHandler(product)}>Add to cart</Button>
    )}
  </Card.Body>
</Card>
)}
```

it's not showing the button out of stock when quantity gets used, What's wrong with the code?
full code: https://github.com/basir/mern-amazona/commit/12e565bf6e1859b963729eaba46a5352962fe9e1

full code with backend : https://github.com/basir/mern-amazona/tree/12e565bf6e1859b963729eaba46a5352962fe9e1

Comment: how are you setting countInStock to 0 once some quantity gets bought?

Comment: sorry kinda new to react , i dont yet full know how to change that

Comment: i tried to put this line product.countInStock--  after the if statement and it worked but if refresh the page it doesn't keep the button disabled , which makes me think  there is a better way to do it

Comment: is your countingStock a state variable? can you include the bit of code that declares it? I can see it comes from your props, but I can't see any logic that works around that variable

Comment: yes all code in the links provided

Comment: I'm happy to look at the code you have for this logic here, I'm not going to go through your entire project on github trying to find it though

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could start you out. There's no need to make 2 buttons. You can just manipulate the state of the button using your logic

```js
const isOutOfStock = product.countInStock === 0
const buttonText = isOutOfStock ? "Out of stock" : "Add to cart"

<Button color="light" disabled={isOutOfStock} onClick={() => addToCartHandler(product)}>{buttonText}</Button>
```

Comment: i tried that it didnt help since countInStock isn't updating